# Internet Explorer broken images

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've recently started testing my website in Internet Explorer and found out that my images are broken. They are "noisy" in photography terms. How can I fix that?

Comment: If this is a programming question at all then the info to reproduce should be in the question not an external site.

Comment: "Noisy" means pixelated, darker and colors are not corresponding to the real one

Answer (score 2):

Your images are "noisy" (or distorted, pixelated) because they are resized by the browser, and not by a professional image processing program. Once you use [very large images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu3Gt.jpg) and set them with `width="750"` and `height="450"`, you let each browser do the graphic work of resizing and rendering them, and each browser does that differently.

To avoid that, if you want [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu3Gt.jpg) to be 750 x 450 pixels, resize it using an image processing program, and omit its dimensions from your `<img>` tag.

Also, since your images are `.JPG` format, make sure you release them with a high quality (Personally, I use `.PNG` since it renders better on all browers, but that is debatable).